# How to compare two files and output lines which do not appear in the first?

Tags: command-line, bash, diff, file-comparison, coreutils

If I have a file `A` containing a list of fields:

```
2017-04-23
2017-04-30
2017-05-07
2017-05-14
2017-05-21
2017-05-28
2017-06-04
2017-06-11
2017-06-18
2017-06-25
```

And another file `B` containing a list of fields:

```
2017-04-23
2017-04-30
2017-05-07
2017-05-14
2017-05-21
2017-05-28
2017-06-04
2017-06-11
2017-06-18
2017-06-25
2017-07-02
2017-07-09
2017-07-16
2017-07-23
```

How can I quickly diff these two files where I want to know all fields in file `B` which are **not** present in file `A`?

This is not a regular diff where I want to see a relative difference between files but more like a hash comparison where each line is an entry in a map. I want to get a list of all lines in file `B` which are not present in file `A` so that I can remove them where each line in file `A` represents a directory which is to be preserved.

I am looking for a Bash/CoreUtils solution.

Answer (score 3):

If your files are sorted, you can use [comm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm):

```
$ comm -13 A B
2017-07-02
2017-07-09
2017-07-16
2017-07-23
```

with options:

- -1 :   suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
- -3 :   suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)

Comment: And if they're not sorted, you can sort them with process substitution `<(sort filename)`

Answer (score 2):

`grep` is the right tool for the job, although it's neither Bash nor from CoreUtils:

```
grep -Fxvf A B
```

All these options are POSIX compliant. From [`man 1 grep`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/grep/):

> `-f pattern_file`
>
> Read  one  or more  patterns  from the file named by the pathname `pattern_file`. Patterns in `pattern_file` shall be terminated by a .  A null pattern can be  specified by  an empty line in pattern_file. Unless the `-E` or `-F` option is also specified, each pattern shall be treated as a BRE, as described in the Base Definitions volume of POSIX.1-2008, Section 9.3, Basic Regular Expressions.
>
> `-F`
>
> Match using fixed strings. Treat each pattern specified as a string instead of a regular expression. If an input line contains any of the patterns as a  contiguous  sequence of  bytes, the line shall be matched. A null string shall match every line.
>
> `-v`
>
> Select lines not matching any of the specified patterns. If the `-v` option is not specified, selected lines shall be those that match any of  the  specified  patterns.
>
> `-x`
>
> Consider only input lines that use all characters in the line excluding the terminating  to match an entire fixed string or regular expression to  be matching lines.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with some pipes

```
cat A B|sort|uniq -u
```

edit- UUOC

There is no need of cat

```
sort A B|uniq -u
```

Comment: This treats `A` and `B` equally, while in the original problem these files are not interchangeable. What if there is a line in `A` which is not in `B`?

Comment: @Kamil Yes, you're right. I misunderstood the question, this will print all lines not duplicated on both files, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: Fix: `sort A A B | uniq -u`. :)

Comment: It works :) nice fix. But there is another problem with my solution, the output will appear sorted, maybe would be a problem for OP purposes.

Comment: Did you read the last paragraph of the question? He just wants to get a list of directories to remove, it doesn't sound like order matters. Also, his input files appear to be sorted.